# Appending array data to JSON file. AngularJs using ngCordova file Plugin

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am new to angularJs and i am using Ionic framework.

i have an existing JSON file. that is like this

```
[{"name":"sample"}]
```

When i append the file with new data, this is how it get appended

```
[{"name":"sample"},[{"name":"sample2"}]]
```

but i want my file to be like this

```
[{"name":"sample"},{"name":"sample2"}]
```

here is my code:

```
var savearray =[];
$cordovaFile.readAsText('user.json')
            .then(function (success) {
                $scope.quotes = JSON.parse(success);
                 savearray.unshift(JSON.parse(success,true));
                console.log("Successful in reading the file initially:"+JSON.stringify(savearray));
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("error reading the file"+JSON.stringify(error))
                    });
```

and this is how i write my data to the file.

```
$scope.saveQuote = function(data){

    savearray.unshift(data);    
     $cordovaFile.writeFile('user.json',JSON.stringify(savearray),{append:false})
      .then(function (success) {
        console.log("success the file has been created")
      }, function (error) {
        console.log("error"+JSON.stringify(error))
      });
}
```

I would be glad if anyone could help me. thanks.

Comment: What is data? If it is an array, then it would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: I should add, if it is an array, try to concat - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat.

Comment: It is an array.  i got it bye the way. when i read the data i used the unshift. so the array went inside the savearray variable.  i just used the = operator.